# Как работает web приложение java?

Tags: java, spring, java-ee, servlet, glassfish

Кто-нибудь может объяснить как работает java web приложение с аннотациями и spring-mvc совместно с сервером приложений? (В моем случае это Glassfish 4)

Когда мы работаем с консольным приложением java, мы указываем команде java имя скомилированного класса. Я так понимаю, JRE ищет в указанном классе метод `public static void main(String args[])` и выполняет его. И этот метод main считается точкой входа в программу.

1. А когда у нас web приложение, у нас имеется какая-то точка входа? Я по началу думал, что точка входа это `web.xml`. Но если мы используем `spring-mvc` и конфигурируем его с помощью аннотаций, то я так понял `web.xml` вообще может быть пустым.
2. Когда глассфишу скармливается war'ник, то я так понимаю в памяти создаются экземпляры классов которые помечены аннотациями `@Service` и `@Controller`, но кто их создает? Я читал, что это делает спринг, в рамках его `IoC`, `DI` и его контейнерной роли, но спринг тоже кто-то должен запустить?
3. По логике, инициализация спринга должна происходить при явном или неявном вызове его конструкторов в точке входа, но где тогда она? Или его инициализацию производит сервер приложений? Но каким образом мы указываем ему это сделать?

   Вот мой `SpringInitializer`, я так понимаю основная магия происходит здесь?
4. Этот код выполняет Glassfish? Как он понимает, что именно этот класс надо выполнить?

```java
import javax.servlet.MultipartConfigElement;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class SpringInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { SpringConfiguration.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    } 
}
```

Я рылся в руководстве Шилдта по Java, а также в Spring in Action, и пару недель пробую различные запросы по сабжу в гугл. Или в этих книгах не было явных ответов на эти вопросы, или я их пропустил, или не понял.

Буду признателен за объяснение, или если кто тыкнет носом где читать.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Я рылся в руководстве Шилдта по Java, а также в Spring in Action

Если вы хотите разобраться с базовыми механизмами работы веб-приложений  начинать стоит со спецификации Servlet API ([3.0](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-oth-JSpec/), [3.1](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html)).

> 1. А когда у нас web приложение, у нас имеется какая-то точка входа?

Как таковой точки входа нет. Есть контейнер сервлетов, который берет ваш WAR и, если все хорошо, стартует жизненный цикл вашего веб-приложения: устанавливает параметры, оповещает слушателей, пробрасывает запросы в сервлеты, пропускает их через фильтры. По сути, контейнер сервлетов занимается тем, что оперирует объектами, которые можно описать в `web.xml`, а, начиная с 3й версии спецификации, он должен уметь искать их и без `web.xml`.

> 2. ... но кто их создает? Я читал, что это делает спринг, в рамках его IoC, DI и его контейнерной роли, но спринг тоже кто-то должен запустить?

Все верно, IoC-контейнер спринга (а именно [`AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.html) в вашем случае) сканирует видимый ему `CLASSPATH` и создает ваши бины, ориентируясь на аннотации. Осталось понять, кто создает экземпляр этого `ApplicationContext` и запускает его жизненный цикл (см. ниже).

> 3. По логике, инициализация спринга должна происходить при явном или неявном вызове его конструкторов в точке входа, но где тогда она? Или его инициализацию производит сервер приложений? Но каким образом мы указываем ему это сделать?

Вы очень верно рассуждаете. Начиная со спецификации Servlet API 3.0 появилась возможность не использовать web.xml. Но контейнер сервлетов должен как-то узнать, где находится код, инициализирующий веб-приложение. Тут помогает механизм, известный как [Service Provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Service%20Provider). Если коротко, он ищет в `CLASSPATH` для контейнера сервлетов файл-дескриптор `META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer`, который указывает на реализацию интерфейса [`ServletContainerInitializer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html?is-external=true). В случае Spring-а это будет класс [`SpringServletContainerInitializer`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/SpringServletContainerInitializer.html).

Давайте без стеснения посмотрим на [его исходники](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-web/4.2.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/web/SpringServletContainerInitializer.java#SpringServletContainerInitializer). На объявлении класса висит аннотация `@HandlesTypes`:

```
@HandlesTypes(WebApplicationInitializer.class)
public class SpringServletContainerInitializer implements ServletContainerInitializer {}
```

По контракту интерфейса `ServletContainerInitializer` контейнер обязуется передать конкретной реализации в её единственный метод `onStartup` коллекцию классов, попадающих в перечисленные в аннотации `@HandlesTypes`. Здесь у нас указан только интерфейс `WebApplicationInitializer`, поэтому Glassfish передаст все найденные реализации [`WebApplicationInitializer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html). Для каждой реализации будет создан экземпляр и вызван метод `onStartup`:

```
for (WebApplicationInitializer initializer : initializers) {
    initializer.onStartup(servletContext);
}
```

И именно ваш `SpringInitializer` является такой реализацией. Кроме того `SpringInitializer` наследует [`AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.html). И вот именно этот `AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer` и "запускает Spring", создавая `WebApplicationContext`. Все сошлось.

---

PS. Читайте спецификации и ознакомьтесь с JavaDoc упомянутых в моем ответе классов. В Spring вообще любят подробно описывать все "магические" механизмы в документации ключевых абстрактных классов и интерфейсов.

Answer (score 9):

Точка входа в виде метода `main` есть в любом Java приложении. Просто в случае web приложений **исполняемой** Java программой является **контейнер сервлетов / сервер приложений** (вот, например, [main-метод Tomcat](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/startup/Bootstrap.java)). WEB приложение **разворачивается** (deploy) внутри контейнера сервлетов. Например, подумайте, если вам требуется задать приложению какие-то аргументы JVM, кому вы их будете передавать? Серверу приложений. Потому что именно он и есть исполняемое приложение, а написанная вами логика существует внутри него и подчиняется спецификации JEE.

До версии JEE 6, когда было введено Servlet 3.0 API, эта спецификация требовала помещать конфигурацию вашего приложения в deployment descriptor - `web.xml`. Начиная с Servlet 3.0 API, этот файл не является обязательным, вместо него приложение может использовать интерфейс [ServletContainerInitializer](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html). Когда вы разворачиваете web-приложение, контейнер сервлетов сканирует *classpath* этого приложения на предмет наличия имплементации указанного интерфейса, а когда находит, то выполняет метод `onStartup()`, в котором должна выполняться инициализация приложения.

Поскольку *Spring Web* построен на сервлетах, все написанное выше относится к нему самым прямым образом. Конфиг на аннотациях в Spring доступен с версии Servlet 3.0+ API. Реализация интерфейса `ServletContainerInitializer` находится в модуле `spring-web`, вы его получаете сразу как подключаете соответствующую зависимость в maven или gradle. [Взгляните что делает этот код](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/SpringServletContainerInitializer.java). Выдержка из документации:

> Interface which allows a library/runtime to be notified of a web
>   application's startup phase and perform any required programmatic
>   registration of servlets, filters, and listeners in response to it.
>
> Implementations of this interface may be annotated with HandlesTypes,
>   in order to receive (at their onStartup(java.util.Set>,
>   javax.servlet.ServletContext) method) the Set of application classes
>   that implement, extend, or have been annotated with the class types
>   specified by the annotation

Он получает все классы, которые помечены аннотацией `WebApplicationInitializer` и инициализирует их. `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`, если вы посмотрите его иерархию, как раз является таким классом.

Дальше, извините, я просто процитирую [ответ в параллеьного сайта](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21714524/5694145), где то же самое расписано пошагово:

---

## Servlet context listener (web.xml) approach

1. A web application WAR is being deployed by **user**.
2. **Servlet container** (Tomcat) reads `web.xml`.
3. Servlet context listener [`ContextLoaderListener`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener.html) is being instantiated (if defined as `<listener>` inside the `web.xml`) **by servlet container**.

   1. **`ContextLoaderListener`** creates new [`WebApplicationContext`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext.html) with application context XML configuration.
   2. Your ROOT context beans are registered and instantiated by **`BeanFactory`** inside the application context.
4. [`DispatcherServlet`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html) is being instantiated **by servlet container**.

   1. **`DispatcherServlet`** creates its own `WebApplicationContext` (`WEB-INF/{servletName}-servlet.xml` by default) with the ROOT context as its parent.
   2. Your servlet beans are registered and instantiated by [**`BeanFactory`**](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html?is-external=true) inside the application context.
   3. **`DispatcherServlet`** registers some default beans in case you did not provide them yourself.

## Servlet container initializer (non web.xml) approach

This one is possible with Servlet 3 features.

1. A web application WAR is being deployed by **user**.
2. **Servlet container** searches for classes implementing [`ServletContainerInitializer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html) via Java's [`ServiceLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html).
3. Spring's [`SpringServletContainerInitializer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/SpringServletContainerInitializer.html) is found and instantiated **by servlet container**.
4. **Spring's initializer reads** web application's class-path and searches for [`WebApplicationInitializer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html) implementations.
5. Your `WebApplicationInitializer` is found (btw. **check its JavaDoc!!!**) and instantiated **by `SpringServletContainerInitializer`**.

   1. **Your `WebApplicationInitializer`** creates new ROOT [`WebApplicationContext`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext.html) with XML or `@Configuration` based configuration.
   2. **Your `WebApplicationInitializer`** creates new servlet [`WebApplicationContext`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext.html) with XML or `@Configuration` based configuration.
   3. **Your `WebApplicationInitializer`** creates and registers new `DispatcherServlet` with the context from previous step.
6. **Servlet container** finishes the web application initialization and instantiates components which were registered by their class in previous steps (*none* in my example).

---

Т.о. чтобы запустить приложение на Spring при помощи аннотаций, нужно имплементировать интерфейс `WebApplicationInitializer` - можно как напрямую, так и унаследоваться от одного из абстрактных классов, которые есть в поставке, и передать туда конфигурационный файл (в вашем примере SpringConfiguration). Дальше Spring получает из него аннтотации `@EnableWebMvc`, `@ComponentScan` (это самые основные) и вытягивает остальную конфигурацию.

Все вместе это образует `ApplicationContext` (несмотря на то что написано в единственном числе, их может быть несколько) - описание среды окружения приложения, который как раз и предоставляет возможность обращаться в бинам, переменным и прочим ресурсам приложения с помощью аннотаций.

Answer (score 1):

Точкой входа и есть сам `web.xml` к которому обращается контейнер сервлетов при деплое, которым в вашем случае является гласфиш. Когда вы деплоите варку или запускаете проект в своей среде разработки, глазфиш поднимает, все сервлеты и конфигурации из `web.xml`.

1) `web.xml` в спринге не остается пустым, просто его работу с сервлетами берет на себя диспетчер сервлетов спринга, но в `web.xml` мы все равно указываем конфигурации диспетчера.

2)Этот вопрос я несколько раз перечитал и не могу понять его суть. Какой варник и причем здесь аннотации контроллеров и сервисов? Спринг никто запускать не должен, это просто упрощенная версия контейнера бинов, в которой используются аннотации для быстрой и понятной разработки. В памяти создается один бин, который с помощью аннотаций `Autowired` или `Inject` можно инжектить не создавая новых экземпляров этого класса, а в случае нескольких реализаций бина, можно выбрать какую именно вы хотите использовать добавив аннотацию `Qualifier(name="")`.

3)В вашем примере приведен, как я понял, конфигурационный файл, который так же должен быть прописан в вашем `web.xml`. Если вы используете `xml` конфигурации, тогда они явно указываются в веб.хмл в приблизительно таком виде:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Если вы используете классы, тогда как глазфиш понимает, что ему надо дергать это уже зашито в аннотациях самими разработчиками спринга и почему оно так работает, дать ответ я не могу.

Comment: *но в web.xml мы все равно указываем конфигурации диспетчера.* - Нет, с 3й версии сервлетов это уже не обязательно.

Comment: *Спринг никто запускать не должен* - он же не волшебным образом стартует. Кто-то должен где-то создать  `new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext()`.

Comment: @Nofate хм. буду знать, спасибо. у меня просто уже второй проект на спринге и как бы даже ни разу не пересекался с таким как "запуск спринга".

Comment: Попробуйте для тренировки написать консольное приложение, которое будет создавать ApplicationContext и брать бины из xml, например. Многое прояснится.