# Авторегистрация классов в Java

Tags: java, java-ee

Имеется базовый класс (или интерфейс), от которого унаследованы другие классы. например, так:

```
class Basic { /* ... */ };
class Derived1 extends Basic { /* ... */ };
class Derived2 extends Basic { /* ... */ };
class Derived21 extends Derived2 { /* ... */ };
// . . .
```

Иерархия может быть сколь угодно большой и разветвлённой. Некоторые из этих классов нужно занести в список класса-менеджера, который будет ими как-то управлять, например, создавать экземпляры по запросу, выдавать клиентам список доступных им классов и т.п.

Собственно, вопрос. Каким образом "зарегистрировать" эти классы в менеджере? Ясно, что можно сделать очень просто - занести их в код вручную. Но делать этого не хочется потому, что иерархия меняется, причём меняется не одним человеком и велика вероятность пропустить какой-либо класс. Интересует метод автоматического построения списка требуемых классов.

Для решения задачи можно использовать любые конструкции языка Java (Java8 EE), генерировать список можно как при компиляции, так и при выполнении. Но никакие внешние библиотеки (в т.ч. Reflections) использовать нельзя. Максимум - встроенные библиотеки WildFly 10, на котором работает приложение.

Comment: А вот этот [код](http://stackoverflow.com/a/520344/3212712) для поиска классов в пакете пробовали/смотрели?

Comment: Вот ещё [что-то](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7461653/3212712)

Comment: Хм... Почему-то не попадался. Похоже, что сработает. Дадим нужным классам аннотацию и поищем аннотированные классы среди всех. Выполним один раз, при старте приложения в контейнере, поэтому быстродействие не очень критично.

Comment: Рад, если навёл на полезную мысль)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Да это не то что мысль, это практически решение! Спасибо! Пошёл кодировать.

Comment: Потом ответ не забудьте написать) Сам я не очень в этом разбираюсь и кроме ссылок особо ничего выдать не смогу)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Обязательно напишу.

Comment: Хороший вопрос, очень хочется увидеть толковый ответ с примером. Выглядит возможным и понятным, но как обычно на практике множество камней +1

Comment: Если java-ee, то недавно был [вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/500359/), как это работает в spring, там используется стандартный для Servlet 3.0 механизм Service Provider

Comment: Облом... Код по ссылкам, предложенным @ЮрийСПб не заработал. Контейнер (WildFly) выдаёт пути в своей VFS, по которым `File` ничего считать не может...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В спецификации *Servlet 3.0* появился интерфейс [`ServletContainerInitializer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html). У этого интерфейса есть метод [`void onStartup(Set<Class<?>> c, ServletContext ctx)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html#onStartup%28java.util.Set,%20javax.servlet.ServletContext%29). Этот метод вызывается контейнером приложений (в моём случае WildFly) когда контейнер инициализирует приложение. У класса, реализующего данный интерфейс можно задать аннотацию [`@HandlesTypes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/HandlesTypes.html), которая задаёт список классов/интерфейсов/аннотаций, в которых "заинтересована" конкретная реализация интерфейса. Этот список будет передан первым параметром метода `onStartup`. (Если аннотации `@HandlesTypes` нет, первый параметр будет равен `null`).

Для решения задачи была создана собственная аннотация, которой помечаются требуемые классы. Реализация интерфейса `ServletContainerInitializer` объявляет "заинтересованность" в этой аннотации и в результате контейнер при инициализации приложения вызывает метод `onStartup` этой реализации, передав ему список помеченных классов.

Ниже приведён пример кода.

Файл ***src/main/java/so/kff/autoregister/TestAnnotation.java***:

```
package so.kff.autoregister;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)  // Аннотация сохраняется при выполнении.
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)            // Аннотация применяется только к классам.
public @interface TestAnnotation {
    String value() default "";
}
```

Реализации классов:

```
package so.kff.autoregister;

class Basic { /* ... */ };

@TestAnnotation
class Derived1 extends Basic { /* ... */ };

class Derived2 extends Basic { /* ... */ };

@TestAnnotation
class Derived21 extends Derived2 { /* ... */ };

// . . .
```

Файл ***src/main/java/so/kff/autoregister/Manager.java***:

```
package so.kff.autoregister;

import javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.HandlesTypes;
import java.util.Set;

@HandlesTypes(TestAnnotation.class)
public class Manager implements ServletContainerInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(Set<Class<?>> c, ServletContext ctx) throws ServletException {
        if (c != null)
            for (Class<?> clazz : c)
                System.out.println(clazz.getName());
    }
}
```

Чтобы контейнер запускал метод `Manager.onStartup` при инициализации, нужно создать файл `src/main/resources/META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer`, в котором прописать полные имена классов, методы которых должны быть запущены. В нашем случае содержимое должно быть следующим:

```
so.kff.autoregister.Manager
```

Чтобы эта технология работала, реализация интерфейса `ServletContainerInitializer` должна лежать в каком-нибудь *jar*-файле, который, в свою очередь, вкладывается в секцию `WEB-INF/lib` развёртываемого приложения (*war*-файла).

Собираем и разворачиваем наше приложение. В результате в консоли *WildFly* видим следующее:

```
package so.kff.autoregister.Derived1;
package so.kff.autoregister.Derived21;
```

Тем самым классы мы получили. Дальше просто обрабатываем полученные классы так, как нам нужно.